# Скрипт не работает, если заходить через localhost

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, sdk

Я в приложение добавил два домена: `localhost` и `plnkr.co`.

Если заходить через песочницу, то, что я прописал (что должно выводится в консоли), — выводится. Но почему оно не выводится, если заходить через `localhost`?

[image: Скрин консоли, через песочницу]

[Приложение, выложенное на plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/AihG6swFrzqBQatK9NlZ?p=preview)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <h1 id="headerInfo"></h1>
</div>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
VK.init({
  apiId: 5580872
 });

VK.Auth.login(function(response){ 
 if(response.session){    
  console.log('авторизация прошла успешно');
  
  // users.get это первый метод и второй параметр — это объект
  VK.api('users.get', {'name_case': 'dat'}, response => {
   if(response.error){
    alert(response.error.error_msg);
   }
   else{
    console.log(response)
    
    // первый элемент массива (инфа о нас)  https://vk.com/dev/users.get
    let userData = response.response[0]; 
    console.log(userData);
    
    headerInfo.textContent = 
     `Музыка на странице ${userData.first_name} ${userData.last_name}`;
   }
  });
 }
 else{
  alert('Не удалось авторизироваться')
 }
}, 8);
})
```

Но если скрипт запихать в HTML-файл, то работать будет (я не понимаю почему).

Comment: Может  потому что это локальный хост? Скачайте программу для создания локального сервера, должно сработать

Comment: В смысле? я же запускаю, через openserver

Comment: ну насколько я понял, если работает в веб редакторах, то ошибка только из за того что локальный сервер. Поищите в интернете статьи по API VK, наверняка кто-то пишет про такое